# Testing Tornado app for 4xx status code

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tornado

Consider the following Tornado (v 4.0.2) application, which is a little bit modified version of official [hello world](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/#hello-world) example:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_status(400)
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

As you can see, the only difference here is `set_status` call in `MainHandler`. Now, I save this code into `app.py`, then I open `tests.py` and I put there this simple unit test:

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase, gen_test

from app import application

class SimpleTest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return application

    def get_new_ioloop(self):
        return tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    @gen_test
    def test_bad_request(self):
        request = HTTPRequest(url=self.get_url('/'))
        response = yield self.http_client.fetch(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 400)
```

When I run this test with `python -m tornado.test.runtests tests` I get the following result:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_bad_request (tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 118, in __call__
    result = self.orig_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 494, in post_coroutine
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 418, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 109, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 631, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "tests.py", line 18, in test_bad_request
    response = yield self.http_client.fetch(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 628, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 111, in result
    raise self._exception
HTTPError: HTTP 400: Bad Request

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.022s

FAILED (errors=1)
[E 140929 12:55:59 testing:687] FAIL
```

Obviously this is correct, because the handler sets 400 status code. **But how can I test my application for such case?** I think 4xx codes are useful, so I don't want to give them up. However I'm new to Tornado and I wasn't able to find a way to test them. Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @gen_test
    def test_bad_request(self):
        request = HTTPRequest(url=self.get_url('/'))
        with self.assertRaises(tornado.httpclient.HTTPError) as context:
            yield self.http_client.fetch(request)

        self.assertEqual(context.exception.code, 400)
```

See the documentation for [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Comment: It works indeed. However, instead of ``context.error.code`` there should be ``context.exception.code``. It is also worth mentioning that one should catch ``tornado.httpclient.HTTPError``, not ``tornado.web.HTTPError``. Although the solution doesn't look good to me (why 4xx response is an exception?), the answer is satisfying. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I've updated my answer. I think it makes sense for Tornado's HTTP client to raise an exception if it cannot download a URL for any reason, including a server error. In any case that's the API it provides. =)